# How to create functions which will listen to changes in hashmap?

Tags: java, android, rx-java2, rx-android

```
private HashMap<Integer, Item> items = new Hashmap<>();

private Flowable<Item> observeItemById(int id) {
  return Flowable.create(emitter -> {
    ???
  },BackpressureStrategy.LATEST);
}

private Flowable<List<Item>> observeItems() {
  return Flowable.create(emitter -> {
    ???
  },BackpressureStrategy.LATEST);
}

//For now I update my hashmap just by putting new items or updating their fields in Item object
```

Each time when I call these functions I would like to create "new instance" of those functions / "new listener".
When I invoke observeItems() I would like to emit list when there will be any changes in that list.
But when I call observeItemById(int id), it should be emitted when there will be a change in that Item object.

How should I create these functions?

How should I create my hashmap and later update it to emit these changes?

Comment: What is `id` in `observeItemById(int id)` method? a key for map entry?

Comment: @AkakiKapanadze It's a key for map entry.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
class Item

class ObservableHashMap(private val map: MutableMap<Int, Item> = mutableMapOf()) : MutableMap<Int, Item> by map {

    private val changesSubject = PublishSubject.create<Pair<Int, Item>>()

    override fun put(key: Int, value: Item): Item? {
        return map.put(key, value).also {
            changesSubject.onNext(Pair(key, value))
        }
    }

    override fun remove(key: Int): Item? {
        return map.remove(key)?.also { value ->
            changesSubject.onNext(Pair(key, value))
        }
    }

    fun observeItemById(id: Int): Flowable<Item> {
        return changesSubject.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
                .filter { (key) -> key == id }.map { (_, value) -> value }
    }

    fun observeItems(): Flowable<List<Item>> {
        return changesSubject.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
                .map { values.toList() }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about updating Item fields by passing an key and later emit changes?

Answer (score 0):

you could create a wrapper that returns a Flowable.
Then you should override put function and emit the change with that Flowable.